# Assign to a variable in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, variable, assignment

I have the following script and I try to create an empty text file.  I tried `touch` and I tried `echo -n >` - they both fail.

```
#!/bin/bash

set filename_result="contents"

echo "filename=$filename_result" # Shows: filename=

rm -f "$filename_result".json

touch $filename_result # Error: usage: touch [-A [-][[hh]mm]SS] [-acfhm] [-r file] [-t [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]] file ...
# Note that `% touch myfile` works fine on the command line

touch -- "$filename_result" # Error: touch: : No such file or directory

echo -n > "$filename_result" # Error: No such file or directory

echo "[" >> "$filename_result"

for file in *json
do
    echo "examining file: $file"
    echo "\n" >> "$filename_result"
    cat $file >> "$filename_result"
    echo "\n" >> "$filename_result"
done

echo "\n]" >> "$filename_result"

mv $filename_result "$filename_result".json
```

EDIT: Printing to screen the `filename_result` variable shows that it's empty after setting it?

```
echo "filename=$filename_result" # Shows: filename=
```

Comment: Removing the spacing around = didn't help.

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of excessive redirections inside the `for` loop, just do the `echo` commands etc. and then redirect the loop itself with `for ...; do ...; done >>"$filename_result"`.  The `touch` is also not needed as redirecting to a file creates the file if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: In my computer works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
filename_result=contents
touch -- "$filename_result"
```

Or:

```
set contents
touch -- "$1"
```

Comment: For your first solution I get this: touch: : No such file or directory

Comment: ah, I still used 'set' and that was the problem.

Comment: yes I was just going to say in your orig post you have
 `set filename_result="contents"` 
This makes $1 = filename_result="contents" not just contents.

Answer (score 15):

`set filename_result="contents"` does not assign a value to `filename_result`. It assigns to the first positional parameter and the value itself is `filename_result=contents`. Example:

```
$ set filename_result="contents"
$ echo "$1"
filename_result=contents
```

The variable `filename_result` doesn't exist, `$filename_result` expands to nothing and `"$filename_result"` is equivalent to `""`.

Instead of `set filename_result="contents"` you want just

```
filename_result="contents"
```

Comment: This answer explains that the problem in the question is the use of `set`. +1

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to create a JSON array with the contents of several JSON files as elements.  I'm noticing that you omit inserting a comma between the contents of each file.  This would result in invalid JSON.

Instead, you may want to replace your script with the command

```
jq -s . ./*.json >outfile
```

This would read all files whose name matches `*.json` in the current directory, and create a single array with each file's JSON document being an element.  The output would be written to `outfile`.

`jq` is a command line JSON parser, available for most Unices (check your package manager).  The `-s` (or `--slurp`) option does exactly what I've just described (read into array).

The `.` is the "identity filter" which has the effect of just passing data through.

---

About your code:

Apart from using `set` to try to set a variable (this has been [pointed out by Kamil Maciorowski](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/571394/116858) already, and that is how it's done in the `csh` and `tcsh` shells), your output could be simplified by grouping some commands together, especially the ones inside the loop.  The `touch` is also not needed as redirecting into a non-existing file creates it.

This is my own take on the problem, which also inserts that missing comma between the contents of each file:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

outfile=outfile

# Will truncate (empty) the file if it exists,
# or create it if it doesn't.
echo '[' >"$outfile"

# Get a list of all JSON files into the list
# of positional parameters.
set -- ./*.json

# Loop over all but the last file.
# Output each file and a comma.
while [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; do
    # The "current" file that we're working on is "$1",
    # the first one in the list.

    cat "$1"
    echo ,

    shift  # shifts this file off the list
done >>"$outfile

# The last file should not have comma after it.
{
    cat "$1"
    echo ']'
} >>"$outfile"
```

The `while` loop iterates over the JSON files in the list of positional parameters (the list is created with `set`).  We're wanting to output each file followed by a comma, but to handle the last file separately since it shouldn't have a comma after it (it would break the JSON format).  Therefore, the loop iterates until we've shifted off all but the last file from the list (`$#` is the length of the list of positional parameters).

The last file is handled by the `{ ...; }` at the end.  Grouping a set of commands inside curly braces allows us to redirect the output of all those commands at once with a single redirection.  Likewise, the loop's output can be redirected with a single redirection.

---

The same approach, but using GNU `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN   { print "[" }
             { print }
     ENDFILE { if (FILENAME != ARGV[ARGC-1]) print "," }
     END     { print "]" }' *.json
```

GNU `awk` has, apart from the standard `BEGIN` and `END` blocks (here used for outputting the initial `[` and final `]` delimiters of the array), a `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE` block.  These are (not surprisingly) triggered before and just after processing each individual input file.  We use `ENDFILE` here to output the comma between each file's contents, except for after the last file.

The `{ print }` block just passes each line of each file through, unmodified.

`FILENAME`, `ARGV` and `ARGC` are variables that GNU `awk` will automatically fill with the current filename, the list of arguments given to the script (filenames in this case), and the number of filenames, respectively.

Comment: Love this answer.  I used your suggestion of jq to do just that.  The GNU awk solution also looks great.  Interestingly I was attempting to solve this problem next, and had problems with inserting the comma.  Many thanks!